CodeceptJS become slow after an angular update
On my project we have some End to End tests and we use CodeceptJS with Playwright (https://codecept.io/helpers/Playwright/). These tests are launched by the developers on their laptop and by our CI/CD Jenkins pipeline.
On angular 12 the Scenarios are "fast" on the dev laptop and on our Jenkins server, the average time to complete a scenario is 7-8s.
Actually I'm trying to update angular from 12 to 16 (a necessary library of our project can use only angular 16 for the moment) but the tests become very slow on our Jenkins server, whereas on the laptop it's still fast.
On Jenkins with angular 16 the average time is 13-14s, whereas on the devs laptop it take 7-8s.
To resume :
Angular 12

Jenkins -> 7-8s
Devs laptop -> 7-8s

Angular 16

Jenkins 13-14s
Devs laptop -> 7-8s

I don't understand why.. Do you have any idea ?
It's a big problem for us, the tests failed because it's too slow and the time to deploy a new version become too long.
The version of the CodeceptJS npm library is 3.6.1
The devs laptops use windows 11
The jenkins server use Ubuntu 20.04
The CodeceptJS config used to execute the tests on the devs laptops
require('ts-node/register');
const { locator } = require('codeceptjs');

const { setHeadlessWhen } = require('@codeceptjs/configure');

// turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
// export HEADLESS=true && npx codeceptjs run
setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

exports.config = {
  tests: './tests/scenarios/**/*_test.ts',
  output: './output',
  // The retry option will impact the stacktrace size,
  // to debug your test you can comment all this object configuration.
  retry: {
    Scenario: 2
  },
  helpers: {
    'Playwright': {
      url: '',
      show: true,
      browser: 'chromium',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        chromeOptions: {
          args: ['--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'],
        },
      },
      restart: 'session'
    },
    'MockDataHelper': {
      require: './tests/helpers/mockDataHelper.ts',
    },
    'ChaiWrapper': {
      'require': 'codeceptjs-chai'
    },
    'FormsHelper': {
      require: './tests/helpers/forms_helper.ts',
    },
    'TextGrabber': {
      require: './tests/helpers/textgrabber_helper.ts',
    },
    ....
  },
  include: {
    ...
  },
  bootstrap: () => {
    locator.addFilter((providedLocator, locatorObj) => {
      if (typeof providedLocator === 'string') {
        if (providedLocator.indexOf('&') !== -1) {
          locatorObj.value = providedLocator.replace(/&(\w+)/gm, '*[local-name()=\'$1\']');
          locatorObj.type = 'xpath';
        }
      }
    });
  },
  mocha: {},
  name: '',
  plugins: {
    'retryFailedStep': {
      enabled: true,
    },
    'tryTo': {
      enabled: true,
    },
    'screenshotOnFail': {
      enabled: true,
    },
    'allure': {
      enabled: true
    },
    'pauseOnFail': {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
};


The CodeceptJS config used to execute the tests on the Jenkins server
require('ts-node/register');
const { locator } = require('codeceptjs');

const { setHeadlessWhen } = require('@codeceptjs/configure');

// turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
// export HEADLESS=true && npx codeceptjs run
setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

exports.config = {
  tests: './tests/scenarios/**/*_test.ts',
  output: 'xxx',
  // retry: {
  //   Scenario: 3
  // },
  helpers: {
    'Playwright': {
      url: 'xxx',
      show: false,
      browser: 'chromium',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [
            '--headless',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disk-cache-size=1',
            '--max_old_space_size=8192',
            '--disable-gl-drawing-for-tests'
          ],
        },
        // close all unexpected popups
        unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'dismiss',
      },
      restart: 'session'
    },
    'MockDataHelper': {
      require: './tests/helpers/mockDataHelper.ts',
    },
    'ChaiWrapper': {
      'require': 'codeceptjs-chai'
    },
    ....
  },
  include: {
xxx
  },
  bootstrap: () => {
    locator.addFilter((providedLocator, locatorObj) => {
      if (typeof providedLocator === 'string') {
        if (providedLocator.indexOf('&') !== -1) {
          locatorObj.value = providedLocator.replace(/&(\w+)/gm, '*[local-name()=\'$1\']');
          locatorObj.type = 'xpath';
        }
      }
    });
  },
  mocha: {},
  name: 'xxx',
  plugins: {
    'pauseOnFail': {},
    'retryFailedStep': {
      enabled: true,
    },
    'tryTo': {
      enabled: true,
    },
    'screenshotOnFail': {
      enabled: true,
    },
    'allure': {
      'enabled': true,
      'outputDir': 'allure-tests'
    }
  },
};


We tried to add more RAM to the jenkins server but it's just reduce the time Scenario completion time by 1s. Now the RAM is 20g

Issue solved. On each test, the generated output files cause an angular rebuild and force my navigator to refresh the page. These refresh force the test to wait and can fail the test
